# Yajra DataTable (search box and loading data) response very slow around 15 sec. and more

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, datatable, yajra-datatable

I'm using [Yajra DataTable](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables) with Laravel. but the table loaded very small and take around 15 seconds and more. The reason is the for loop and if conditions inside `addColumn`, which make it slow.

I only know this way (by using `addColumn`) to embed html tags in the table. While I need to put select tag, buttons, and other links based on some conditions. where these tags make loading the table very slow.

This is my Ajax code:

```
var allUsersTable = $('.allleads').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: {
                    url: "customer/GetAllcusts",
                },
                columns: [
                    {"data": "note", "name": "note", orderable: false, searchable: false},
                    {"data": "sms", "name": "sms"},
                    {"data": "assign", "name": "assign"},
                ],
                bSort: false,
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                     'excel', 'pdf', 'print', 'colvis'
                ]
            });
```

and herein the function in controller to load the data:

```
return DataTables::of($allClients)
            ->addColumn('note', function ($allClient) {
                return '<a style="cursor: pointer" title="Add Note" onclick="addNotes(' . $allClient->id . ',' . $allClient->quote_id . ',this)"><i class="material-icons">event_note </i></a>';
            })
            ->addColumn('sms', function ($allClient) {
                return '<a style="cursor: pointer" title="Send SMS" id="send_smsclick" onclick="send_smsclick(' . $allClient->id . ',' . $allClient->primary_number . ')" ><i class="material-icons notranslate">message</i></a>';
            })
->addColumn('assign', function ($allClient) use ($user_status, $all_users) {

                if ($user_status == 'Admin') {
                    $options = '<option hidden="true">Select Stuff...</option>';
                    foreach ($all_users as $users) {
                        if ($allClient->user_id == $users->id) {
                            $options = $options . '<option value = "' . $users->id . '" disabled selected >' . $users->name . '</option >';
                        } else {
                            $options = $options . '<option value = "' . $users->id . '" >' . $users->name . '</option>';
                        }
                    }

                    return '<select name="user_id" class="form-control activity_status"
                            onchange="assign_users(' . $allClient->id . ', this)" >' . $options . ' </select>';


                } else {
                    $query = User::find($allClient->user_id);
                    return $query->name;
                }

            })
            ->rawColumns(['note', 'sms', 'assign'])
            ->make(true);
```

I will appreciate any hep to improve the speed to load the table, and lunch the data as well.

Thank u

Answer (score -2):

change :

```
processing: true,
serverSide: true,
```

to :

```
processing: false,
serverSide: false,
```

Comment: both the options are related to AJAX & table processing, hence are needed to be `true` in this case.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it